# How to modify N columns of numpy array at the same time?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

How to modify N columns of numpy array?? For example, I have a numpy array as follows:

```
P  = array([[1, 2, 3, 8, 6],
            [4, 5, 6, 4, 5]
            [0,-2, 5, 3, 0]])
```

How do I change the elements of first, second and forth columns of P?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing):

Here is an example:

```
>>> P[:, [0, 1, 3]] += 10
>>> 
>>> P
array([[11, 12,  3, 18,  6],
       [14, 15,  6, 14,  5],
       [10,  8,  5, 13,  0]])
```